# Reporting Services - Count Column Values if equals A

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset called 'dsAllStuTargetData' - i'm trying to count the number of the 'A' values that appear in the column 'Target'.

I'm doing this using a textbox with an expression, I can count the total number of values using the following:

```
=Count(Fields!Target.Value, "dsAllStuTargetData")
```

However when I try to count where the value equals 'A' it doesn't work.

```
=Count(IIF(Fields!Target.Value, "dsAllStuTargetData")="A",1,0)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For this case you need a `Sum`, not a `Count`, i.e. something like:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Target.Value = "A", 1, 0), "dsAllStuTargetData")
```

`Count` will just count the number of rows; the `IIf` doesn't do anything there - something like `CountDistinct` can be affected in certain cases but this will not work here.

However, `Sum` will take the total of all rows which meet the `IIf` condition, i.e. the total of all `1` values in the DataSet, which is what you're after.

Comment: hello Ian, It's working fine, but what if I want to group by the counting of one field on the base of Date field. How to use Group by or Aggregate with above expression?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIF wants it's arguments in the format:

```
IIF(condition, true part, false part)
```

Which would equate to something like

```
Count(IIF(Fields!Target.Value = "A",1,0),"dsAllStuTargetData")
```

Does that work?

Comment: Hi Matt - unfortunately it doesn't work it still returns the total number of records (23). When in fact it should count 10 'A' values.