# Using Count() and IIF in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I am attempting to count the number of values where the Previous Year Comp is greater than 0. I found examples on StackOverflow but nothing is giving me the count I want.

I have the following expression:

```
= IIF((Fields!Previous_Year_Comp.Value) > "0.00",
      count(Fields!Previous_Year_Comp.Value),0)
```

This expression is counting the 0 values. Keep in mind that this expression has undergone several modifications. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to combine `Sum` and `IIf`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892911/reporting-services-count-column-values-if-equals-a

Comment: Thank you Ian. This worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your **COUNT** should be around your **IIF**.

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Previous_Year_Comp.Value > "0.00", Fields!Previous_Year_Comp.Value, NOTHING)
```

NOTHING is SSRSs NULL that isn't counted with COUNT.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string to an integer value. Try this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Previous_Year_Comp.Value > 0, count(Fields!Previous_Year_Comp.Value),0)
```

Of course, if Previous_Year_Comp is a `VARCHAR` value and not a `DECIMAL or INTEGER`, you may need something like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Previous_Year_Comp.Value <> "0.00", count(Fields!Previous_Year_Comp.Value),0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither solution worked. Prev_Year_Comp is a decimal.

Comment: =count(  IIF(   IIF(Fields!Previous_Year_Comp.Value > 0, true, false)   ,true,0        )   )    I also tried this. No bueno.